# How to remove controls from a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Label`, a `Textbox` and `button3`, `button4` buttons in my `Form`.

On each click `button3` adds new `Label` and `Textbox` under the existing ones.

I want to make `button4` click to remove previously added `Label` and `TextBox`. How can I access to the last value of `index`? Here is code snippet:

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    int index = 1;

    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        t.Name = "txt" + index;
        l.Text = label2.Text;
        l.Width = label2.Width;
        t.Width = textBox2.Width;
        l.Name = "lbl" + index;
        t.Location = new Point(textBox2.Location.X, textBox2.Location.Y + 30 * index);
        l.Location = new Point(label2.Location.X, label2.Location.Y + 30 * index);
        if (index >8)
        {
            button3.Enabled =false;
        }
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y + 30);
        button2.Location = new Point(button2.Location.X, button2.Location.Y + 30);
        this.Controls.Add(l);
        this.Controls.Add(t);
        this.Height += 30;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.Controls.Remove`?

Comment: Try [Control.ControlCollection.Find(string key, bool searchAllChildren)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.100).aspx). "Searches for controls by their Name property and builds an array of all the controls that match."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove controls by name

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (index > 1)
    {
        index--;
        this.Controls.RemoveByKey("txt" + index);
        this.Controls.RemoveByKey("lbl" + index);

        this.Height -= 30;
    }
}
```

`RemoveByKey` is a [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removebykey(v=vs.110).aspx) of `ControlCollection`, which removes the child control with the specified key

---

@LarsTech suggested in a comment that removed controls should be also disposed:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (index > 1)
    {
        index--;
        // get a textBox by name
        Control c = Controls["txt" + index];
        // remove from form
        Controls.Remove(c);
        // clean up
        c.Dispose();

        // repeat for label
        c = Controls["lbl" + index];
        Controls.Remove(c);
        c.Dispose();

        Height -= 30;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought that I have to know the last value of index,seems that I was wrong.

Comment: It might remove the control, but it doesn't *Dispose* of the control.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Stack, when you add a control Push the control to the Stack. When you want to remove a Control, Peek the Stack to get a reference to the last created Control, next remove the Control and finally Pop the Stack.

Sample code would look as such (draft):

```
  private Stack<Control> _Stack = new Stack<Control>();

  private void AddControlEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     this.Controls.Add(addedControl);
     _Stack.Push(addedControl);
  }

  private void RemoveControlEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     //Get a reference to the last added control from the stack.
     var lastAddedControl = _Stack.Peek();
     //Remove the control
     this.Controls.Remove(lastAddedControl);
     //Remove the reference to the control from the stack
     _Stack.Pop();
  }
```

Comment: Isn't it better to save in stack only control name?

Comment: The code above only adds a reference to the control and not a copy of the control . This way you can use the reference to remove the control (instead of searching for the control by name or index)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
 //get reference control
   var control = this.Controls[this.Controls.IndexOfKey("controlName")];
  this.Controls.Remove(control);
  //now dispose if do need it any more
  control.Dispose();
```

Comment: `l` is a variable that only exists in `button3_Click`. He'll have to search by name and remove it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The index variable already have the last value.
You don't need to track it.
use `this.Controls.RemoveByKey();`